# Skill Bias in Gaming Statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, bias

I have a data set consisting of a competitive, semi-deterministic game.
It records all the moves and the final outcome.
I would like to derive a value for each move.

**I already know it is wrong to use "probability of winning given a certain move".**
That is because if this is a good move, then conditioning on this move also selects a subset of better players.
These better players will make other good moves, which contaminates the conditional probability.
I would like to remove this contamination.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is this a well-known problem? 
   If so, where can I find the relevant discussions?
2. If not, then I actually have a cute toy-model solution.
   Where can I find people to discuss about that, and what is the appropriate channel to publish the result? (like a journal?)

Comment: Wat exactly is the problem with "contamination"? If you want skill-agnostic probabilities, then you can run a huge Monte Carlo simulation of random moves for the players and calculate probabilities out of that -- but is it really what you're after..?

Comment: I don't see how you can derive a value for each move in isolation of the state you are in and the skill levels of the player(s).  The probability of winning a baseball game given the batter just a home run is 1 if the score was tied and you are in the bottom of the 9th inning, but not much better than 50% if it's the first batter in the game.

Comment: @Tim: Assume that I do not have full control of this game, so I cannot just Monte-Carlo simulate it. Actually, let's assume that I only record "important" moves.  For example, I may have NBA data recording who makes how many shots, but I certainly do not have the data for how many passes happened in a game.  Thus, I cannot actually reproduce a game from data.

Comment: @jbowman: Here is a special example to show that it is in-principle doable.  Assume that my entire record is from 2 players against each other many times. Player A is more skilled and wins 60% of the time. When Player A takes a certain move, he wins 62% of the time. In this situation, it seems reasonable to be able to derive the true value of such move, right?

My situation is that there are many players, and any 2 of them do not play against each other too often (may even be never). So I invented a cute generalization.

Comment: This paper *Is it a Fallacy to Believe in the Hot Hand in the NBA Three-Point Contest?* may suggest an approach to answering your question. http://www.igier.unibocconi.it/files/548.pdf

Comment: @DJohnson: Thanks. That is interesting to read. Although it is not directly relevant, it gives me some idea about what kind of paper get published by journals.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is my cute little toy model to solve this problem, recently posted on arXiv.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05484

Long story short, my answer is

(Conditional Winning Probability for a move) - (Conditional Winning Probability for being those players who make such move),

then divide by a number that is slightly smaller than 1.